# Area of a circle that is uniformly distributed. But what is my function?

Tags: probability

Let $A$ be a circle in the plane, $R^2$, with radius 2 and the center in $(0,0)$ a point random variable (X,Y) chooses in A where they are uniformly distributed.

I want to know there covariance. But I don't even know what my $f_{x,y}(x,y)$ is here.

I know that I can choose something like $x^2+y^2=4$ or $Area=\pi x^2$ or?

[Points uniformly distributed on a circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3182322/points-uniformly-distributed-on-a-circle)

I read this discussion, but it doesn't appeal to me.

Comment: "... in the plane, $R^3$ ..."?  Is it plane or space?

Comment: @user10354138 plane R^2 shoot

Comment: @sannahoho13 Please clarify one point. Since you are taking about the area, the density function  etc I think $(X,Y) is uniformly distrbuted at points inside and on the circle. Or is it unifromly distributed only on the circumference of the circle? This point is causing confusion  so you should clarify this.

Comment: When you say "in $A$" it is not clear whether you mean $(X,Y)$ has to be a point on the circumference, that is, it is always true that $X^2+Y^2 =4,$ or $(X,Y)$ is a point on the circle or in the region interior to the circle, that is, $X^2+Y^2 \leq 4.$ You get completely different answers depending on which of these you mean. In the case $X^2+Y^2 =4$ there is no probability density function $f_{x,y}$.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are talking about uniform distribution in the circular region. If it is about the circumference of the region then there is no density.

$f_{x,y} (x,y)=\frac 1 {4\pi}$ for $x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 4$ and $0$ for all other $(x,y)$. [This is the definition of uniform distribution].

Comment: okej, so if we change the radius to r instead the function will be $\frac{1}{r pi}$?

Comment: If the radius is $r$ then the density is $\frac  1{\pi r^{2}}$. @sannahoho13

Comment: Kavi, it concerns a circle (not a disc).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $\Phi$ have uniform distribution on $[0,2\pi)$.

Then $(X,Y):=(2\cos\Phi,2\sin\Phi)$ has uniform distribution on circle $\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2=4\}$

Comment: $\int_{circle} f(x,y) dxdi = 1 \rightarrow C = 1/r \phi$ S

Comment: What are you trying to say with that? Btw, according to my hint it is enough to find $\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)=4\mathsf{Cov}(\cos\Phi,\sin\Phi)$. You can apply also that $\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathbb EXY-\mathbb EX\mathbb EY$. You do not need any PDF on the circle. The PDF of $\Phi$ is handsome though.

Comment: But if I want to use E(XY)-.... Then my functions *is* 1/pi*r^2 ?

Comment: $\mathbb EXY=4\mathbb E\cos\Phi\sin\Phi=4\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos\phi\sin\phi d\phi=2\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\sin2\phi d\phi$

Comment: i have never seen this before. not even say in my textbook.. tried to google it, but I can't find anything??? Do you have some url that I can have a look?

Comment: Do you agree that $(2\cos\Phi,2\sin\Phi)$ indeed *has* uniform distribution on the circle if $\Phi$ has uniform distribution on $[0,2\pi)$? That is the essence. If that is settled then we apply [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).